R function 'transform' ignoring argument 'check.names=FALSE'
I'm having issues with the function transform in R and the argument check.names.
For example:
df <- data.frame('A' = sample(1:10), 'B' = sample(1:10), 'C(%)' = NA, check.names = FALSE)

> names(df)
[1] "A"    "B"    "C(%)"

here the argument check.names=FALSE is being respected.
If I now create a new column using transform:
df <- transform(df, 'D(%)' = NaN, check.names = FALSE)

> names(df)
[1] "A"    "B"    "C(%)" "D(%)"

the argument check.names=FALSE is also being respected.
Now, if I try to transform an existing column with
df <- transform(df, 'C(%)' = sample(1:10), check.names = FALSE)

I get the following names
> names(df)
"A"    "B"    "C..." "D..."

where the argument check.names=FALSE seems to be ignored.
Why is that? Is that a bug, or am I missing something?
EDIT: Added the R version:
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          3.3                         
year           2024                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        86002                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
nickname       Angel Food Cake


What's your R version?

@Edward, R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29). I've also added the R version to my question.

Can't reproduce (R 4.4.1), even works without check.names, since it's originally a data.frame argument.

@Andre Wildberg I've just updated R to version 4.4.1 and that solved the issue.

That's good to know, glad that solved it!

Update to 4.4.x
Realease notes for 4.4.0 (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html)

transform.data.frame() no longer adjusts names; in particular, untransformed variables are kept as-is, including those with syntactically invalid names


great, that pins out the changes between R version, cheers!

Probably you can try within instead of transform, for example
within(df,`E(%)` <- 1:10)

According to the description of transform

Warning
This is a convenience function intended for use interactively.
For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting arithmetic
functions, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument
transform can have unanticipated consequences.


Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem
> df <- data.frame("A" = sample(1:10), "B" = sample(1:10), "C(%)" = NA, check.names = FALSE)

> df <- transform(df, "D(%)" = NaN, check.names = FALSE)

> df <- transform(df, "C(%)" = 1:10, check.names = FALSE)

> df
    A  B C(%) D(%)
1  10  8    1  NaN
2   4  4    2  NaN
3   6  9    3  NaN
4   9  1    4  NaN
5   1  6    5  NaN
6   2  7    6  NaN
7   5  5    7  NaN
8   8 10    8  NaN
9   7  2    9  NaN
10  3  3   10  NaN

> names(df)
[1] "A"    "B"    "C(%)" "D(%)"

and here is my version
> version  
               _
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          4.0
year           2024
month          04
day            24
svn rev        86474
language       R
version.string R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
nickname       Puppy Cup


Thanks. Yes, and that's how I'm also working around that problem, by using within. I just wanted to understand why transform is behaving in that way. I will update R to version 4.4.1 and see, if this solves the problem.

@SchlaWiener yes, please try the latest R version, and I believe it should work well
